Get Max date value from append variable array - azure synapse pipeline
In my Synapse pipeline, I am looping through a set of filenames. Inside the loop, I use a "Get Metadata" activity to retrieve the last modified date of each file and append these dates to an array variable using the "Append Variable" activity. After the loop completes, I want to extract the maximum date value from the appended array and store it in a separate variable outside the loop.

outside the loop I have a set variable

Able to retrive the first value using the expression in set variable value as @variables('GetLatestFile')[1]
But not sure about how to get the max value from the values in array. For set variable activity I have the variable type as string.

do you want max date from vlaues of append variable?

Yes, I have all the date values in append variable but I want to get max date from those list of array values

To compare Last modified dates and get max date from it you need to use the if activity as below:

First create RefDateTime variable in pipeline with ample value as 1900-01-01 00:00:00



Then add the If condition activity after get metadata activity where you are getting the last modified date for each file. and add the below expression:

@greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified), ticks(variables('RefDateTime')))


it will check the incoming date for the file is greater than our reference date or not.

After this add set variable in true condition of if condition activity, if condtion meets it will update the RefDateTime variable.


Now you can take set variable activity outside forech activity and fetch the value of RefDateTime in it will return you max value from all the last modified dates.


Thanks it is working only if I run the loop in sequential, otherwise it is not setting the correct values. Any way to make use of append variable activity so that I can avoid running the for loop sequentially

I guess there's a reason you don't want it to run sequentially. Are you averse to having a 2nd ForEach?  I can only think of a couple of options - 1 is that you have a 2nd ForEach, that runs sequentially to determine which of the dates was max.  The other, is that you pass the array to another function (SPROC or something) and have it parse the data to return the max.
